# Scala type bounds versus Foo[_]

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-bounds

I've a `class Bar[T <: Foo]`. What is the difference between type `Bar[_ <: Foo]` and `Bar[_]`? I don't see any semantical difference, since I can't write anything like `new Bar[String]("asdf")`.

However, `scalac` does distinguish them. It looks like it forgets the bounds and consider `Bar[_]` to be a `Bar[_ <: Any]` rather than `Bar[_ <: Foo]`.

Note that this works in Java as expected, unlike in Scala: https://gist.github.com/v6ak/7847548 . I wonder if there is an important semantical difference between Java and Scala I am not aware of. I know there are some differences, for example in generics with primitive types (especially when used together with arrays), but I don't know anything related to this issue.

To make things even stranger, I've disassembled the bytecode from [the mentioned scala code](https://gist.github.com/v6ak/7847548#file-gistfile1-scala) (by [reJ](http://rejava.sourceforge.net/)), disabled generics recognition and found that [method foo returns always a Foo](https://public.v6ak.com/Screenshot%20-%2012072013%20-%2010:11:02%20PM.png).

(I didn't use javap because I can't disable generics recognition there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your examples compile in current milestone, 2.11.0-M7.

Relevant commits: [this one](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/e28c3edda4) and [this one](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/b4751a679a). It seems that this was fixed in 2.11.0-M3.